# How to install missing gem executables using bundler

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler, fastlane

I'm trying to automate app distribution to TestFlight using Fastlane and I'm following the recommendation in the docs to use a Gemfile and bundler.

I have minimal experience with ruby so I followed the instructions but I get an error saying the command could not be found and I need to install the missing gem executables with bundler.

I've been able to reproduce the error after uninstalling bundler and running the following script in an empty directory:

```
sudo gem install bundler
echo 'source "https://rubygems.org"\n\ngem "fastlane"' >> Gemfile
bundle update
bundle exec fastlane
```

stdout:

```
Successfully installed bundler-2.2.17
Parsing documentation for bundler-2.2.17
Done installing documentation for bundler after 2 seconds
1 gem installed
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
Resolving dependencies....................................
Using rake 13.0.3
Using CFPropertyList 3.0.3
Using public_suffix 4.0.6
Using artifactory 3.0.15
Using atomos 0.1.3
Using aws-eventstream 1.1.1
Using aws-partitions 1.458.0
Using jmespath 1.4.0
Using babosa 1.0.4
Using bundler 2.2.17
Using claide 1.0.3
Using colored 1.2
Using colored2 3.1.2
Using highline 2.0.3
Using declarative 0.0.20
Using digest-crc 0.6.3
Using unf_ext 0.0.7.7
Using dotenv 2.7.6
Using emoji_regex 3.2.2
Using excon 0.81.0
Using faraday-excon 1.1.0
Using faraday-net_http 1.0.1
Using faraday-net_http_persistent 1.1.0
Using multipart-post 2.0.0
Using ruby2_keywords 0.0.4
Using fastimage 2.2.3
Using gh_inspector 1.1.3
Using jwt 2.2.3
Using memoist 0.16.2
Using multi_json 1.15.0
Using os 1.1.1
Using httpclient 2.8.3
Using mini_mime 1.1.0
Using trailblazer-option 0.1.1
Using uber 0.1.0
Using retriable 3.1.2
Using rexml 3.2.5
Using webrick 1.7.0
Using google-cloud-errors 1.1.0
Using json 2.5.1
Using mini_magick 4.11.0
Using naturally 2.2.1
Using plist 3.6.0
Using rubyzip 2.3.0
Using security 0.1.3
Using terminal-notifier 2.0.0
Using unicode-display_width 1.7.0
Using tty-screen 0.8.1
Using tty-cursor 0.7.1
Using word_wrap 1.0.0
Using nanaimo 0.3.0
Using rouge 2.0.7
Using addressable 2.7.0
Using aws-sigv4 1.2.3
Using commander 4.6.0
Using unf 0.1.4
Using aws-sdk-core 3.114.0
Using domain_name 0.5.20190701
Using representable 3.1.1
Using simctl 1.6.8
Using terminal-table 1.8.0
Using tty-spinner 0.9.3
Using xcodeproj 1.19.0
Using xcpretty 0.3.0
Using aws-sdk-kms 1.43.0
Using http-cookie 1.0.3
Using xcpretty-travis-formatter 1.0.1
Using aws-sdk-s3 1.94.1
Using faraday 1.4.1
Using faraday-cookie_jar 0.0.7
Using faraday_middleware 1.0.0
Using signet 0.15.0
Using google-cloud-env 1.5.0
Using googleauth 0.16.2
Using google-cloud-core 1.6.0
Using google-apis-core 0.3.0
Using google-apis-androidpublisher_v3 0.3.0
Using google-apis-playcustomapp_v1 0.2.0
Using google-apis-iamcredentials_v1 0.3.0
Using google-apis-storage_v1 0.3.0
Using google-cloud-storage 1.31.0
Using fastlane 2.183.2
Bundle updated!
```

stderr:

```
Following files may not be writable, so sudo is needed:
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/build_info
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/cache
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/doc
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/extensions
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/plugins
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/specifications
bundler: command not found: fastlane
Install missing gem executables with `bundle install`
```

Gemfile.lock

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    CFPropertyList (3.0.3)
    addressable (2.7.0)
      public_suffix (>= 2.0.2, < 5.0)
    artifactory (3.0.15)
    atomos (0.1.3)
    aws-eventstream (1.1.1)
    aws-partitions (1.458.0)
    aws-sdk-core (3.114.0)
      aws-eventstream (~> 1, >= 1.0.2)
      aws-partitions (~> 1, >= 1.239.0)
      aws-sigv4 (~> 1.1)
      jmespath (~> 1.0)
    aws-sdk-kms (1.43.0)
      aws-sdk-core (~> 3, >= 3.112.0)
      aws-sigv4 (~> 1.1)
    aws-sdk-s3 (1.94.1)
      aws-sdk-core (~> 3, >= 3.112.0)
      aws-sdk-kms (~> 1)
      aws-sigv4 (~> 1.1)
    aws-sigv4 (1.2.3)
      aws-eventstream (~> 1, >= 1.0.2)
    babosa (1.0.4)
    claide (1.0.3)
    colored (1.2)
    colored2 (3.1.2)
    commander (4.6.0)
      highline (~> 2.0.0)
    declarative (0.0.20)
    digest-crc (0.6.3)
      rake (>= 12.0.0, < 14.0.0)
    domain_name (0.5.20190701)
      unf (>= 0.0.5, < 1.0.0)
    dotenv (2.7.6)
    emoji_regex (3.2.2)
    excon (0.81.0)
    faraday (1.4.1)
      faraday-excon (~> 1.1)
      faraday-net_http (~> 1.0)
      faraday-net_http_persistent (~> 1.1)
      multipart-post (>= 1.2, < 3)
      ruby2_keywords (>= 0.0.4)
    faraday-cookie_jar (0.0.7)
      faraday (>= 0.8.0)
      http-cookie (~> 1.0.0)
    faraday-excon (1.1.0)
    faraday-net_http (1.0.1)
    faraday-net_http_persistent (1.1.0)
    faraday_middleware (1.0.0)
      faraday (~> 1.0)
    fastimage (2.2.3)
    fastlane (2.183.2)
      CFPropertyList (>= 2.3, < 4.0.0)
      addressable (>= 2.3, < 3.0.0)
      artifactory (~> 3.0)
      aws-sdk-s3 (~> 1.0)
      babosa (>= 1.0.3, < 2.0.0)
      bundler (>= 1.12.0, < 3.0.0)
      colored
      commander (~> 4.6)
      dotenv (>= 2.1.1, < 3.0.0)
      emoji_regex (>= 0.1, < 4.0)
      excon (>= 0.71.0, < 1.0.0)
      faraday (~> 1.0)
      faraday-cookie_jar (~> 0.0.6)
      faraday_middleware (~> 1.0)
      fastimage (>= 2.1.0, < 3.0.0)
      gh_inspector (>= 1.1.2, < 2.0.0)
      google-apis-androidpublisher_v3 (~> 0.1)
      google-apis-playcustomapp_v1 (~> 0.1)
      google-cloud-storage (~> 1.31)
      highline (~> 2.0)
      json (< 3.0.0)
      jwt (>= 2.1.0, < 3)
      mini_magick (>= 4.9.4, < 5.0.0)
      multipart-post (~> 2.0.0)
      naturally (~> 2.2)
      plist (>= 3.1.0, < 4.0.0)
      rubyzip (>= 2.0.0, < 3.0.0)
      security (= 0.1.3)
      simctl (~> 1.6.3)
      terminal-notifier (>= 2.0.0, < 3.0.0)
      terminal-table (>= 1.4.5, < 2.0.0)
      tty-screen (>= 0.6.3, < 1.0.0)
      tty-spinner (>= 0.8.0, < 1.0.0)
      word_wrap (~> 1.0.0)
      xcodeproj (>= 1.13.0, < 2.0.0)
      xcpretty (~> 0.3.0)
      xcpretty-travis-formatter (>= 0.0.3)
    gh_inspector (1.1.3)
    google-apis-androidpublisher_v3 (0.3.0)
      google-apis-core (~> 0.1)
    google-apis-core (0.3.0)
      addressable (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.1)
      googleauth (~> 0.14)
      httpclient (>= 2.8.1, < 3.0)
      mini_mime (~> 1.0)
      representable (~> 3.0)
      retriable (>= 2.0, < 4.0)
      rexml
      signet (~> 0.14)
      webrick
    google-apis-iamcredentials_v1 (0.3.0)
      google-apis-core (~> 0.1)
    google-apis-playcustomapp_v1 (0.2.0)
      google-apis-core (~> 0.1)
    google-apis-storage_v1 (0.3.0)
      google-apis-core (~> 0.1)
    google-cloud-core (1.6.0)
      google-cloud-env (~> 1.0)
      google-cloud-errors (~> 1.0)
    google-cloud-env (1.5.0)
      faraday (>= 0.17.3, < 2.0)
    google-cloud-errors (1.1.0)
    google-cloud-storage (1.31.0)
      addressable (~> 2.5)
      digest-crc (~> 0.4)
      google-apis-iamcredentials_v1 (~> 0.1)
      google-apis-storage_v1 (~> 0.1)
      google-cloud-core (~> 1.2)
      googleauth (~> 0.9)
      mini_mime (~> 1.0)
    googleauth (0.16.2)
      faraday (>= 0.17.3, < 2.0)
      jwt (>= 1.4, < 3.0)
      memoist (~> 0.16)
      multi_json (~> 1.11)
      os (>= 0.9, < 2.0)
      signet (~> 0.14)
    highline (2.0.3)
    http-cookie (1.0.3)
      domain_name (~> 0.5)
    httpclient (2.8.3)
    jmespath (1.4.0)
    json (2.5.1)
    jwt (2.2.3)
    memoist (0.16.2)
    mini_magick (4.11.0)
    mini_mime (1.1.0)
    multi_json (1.15.0)
    multipart-post (2.0.0)
    nanaimo (0.3.0)
    naturally (2.2.1)
    os (1.1.1)
    plist (3.6.0)
    public_suffix (4.0.6)
    rake (13.0.3)
    representable (3.1.1)
      declarative (< 0.1.0)
      trailblazer-option (>= 0.1.1, < 0.2.0)
      uber (< 0.2.0)
    retriable (3.1.2)
    rexml (3.2.5)
    rouge (2.0.7)
    ruby2_keywords (0.0.4)
    rubyzip (2.3.0)
    security (0.1.3)
    signet (0.15.0)
      addressable (~> 2.3)
      faraday (>= 0.17.3, < 2.0)
      jwt (>= 1.5, < 3.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.10)
    simctl (1.6.8)
      CFPropertyList
      naturally
    terminal-notifier (2.0.0)
    terminal-table (1.8.0)
      unicode-display_width (~> 1.1, >= 1.1.1)
    trailblazer-option (0.1.1)
    tty-cursor (0.7.1)
    tty-screen (0.8.1)
    tty-spinner (0.9.3)
      tty-cursor (~> 0.7)
    uber (0.1.0)
    unf (0.1.4)
      unf_ext
    unf_ext (0.0.7.7)
    unicode-display_width (1.7.0)
    webrick (1.7.0)
    word_wrap (1.0.0)
    xcodeproj (1.19.0)
      CFPropertyList (>= 2.3.3, < 4.0)
      atomos (~> 0.1.3)
      claide (>= 1.0.2, < 2.0)
      colored2 (~> 3.1)
      nanaimo (~> 0.3.0)
    xcpretty (0.3.0)
      rouge (~> 2.0.7)
    xcpretty-travis-formatter (1.0.1)
      xcpretty (~> 0.2, >= 0.0.7)

PLATFORMS
  universal-darwin-20

DEPENDENCIES
  fastlane

BUNDLED WITH
   2.2.17
```

My suspicion is that is a RubyGems environment error but a day has gone by now and I have not been able to figure out what the issue is.

Comment: You can try this https://bundler.io/man/bundle-binstubs.1.html

Comment: This works @andriy-baran, but do you have any idea why the bundle exec command wasn't working.